# Component output renders incorrectly after running Nuxt production/build

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I've got a headless Nuxt 2 (2.17.1) website running in production mode (NODE_ENV=production), which renders a component imported from a package incorrectly.

The problem is that the name of the component is not being parsed (the element is `<vuescrollprogressbar>` instead of a `<div>`). However, it does seem to work (inside the component, I see html attributes changing on scroll) and there's no error or warnings in the console. The incorrect rendering only happens in production mode, development mode goes fine. You can see the difference in the screenshots below.

Production mode
[image: Production mode]
Development mode
[image: Development mode]

The component itself is a scroll progress bar for Vue: https://github.com/guillaumebriday/vue-scroll-progress-bar (1.0.0) which I added to my dependancies in my package.json.

```json
"dependencies": { "@guillaumebriday/vue-scroll-progress-bar": "^1.0.0",
```

I tried importing this as a global component through a plugin and importing it directly from the layout. As the docs say, my plugin code is as follows:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueScrollProgressBar from '@guillaumebriday/vue-scroll-progress-bar'

Vue.use(VueScrollProgressBar)
```

And I include it in my nuxt.config.js file like this, together with some other plugins.
Tried adding client-side rendering as well.

```js
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/bootstrap.client.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/dompurify.client.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/progressbar.js'},
    { src: '~/plugins/gtm.client.js', }
  ],
```

Also tried importing it directly in my layouts/default.vue, but the results are the same:

```html
<template>
  <div class="page">

    <PageHeader />
    <Nuxt />
    <PageFooter />

    <OffcanvasNav />

    <VueScrollProgressBar height=".25rem" background-color="linear-gradient(86deg, rgba(118, 72, 150, 1) 0%, rgba(118, 72, 150, 1) 40%, rgba(233, 44, 168, 1) 100%)" />

  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { VueScrollProgressBar } from "@guillaumebriday/vue-scroll-progress-bar";

import PageHeader from "~/components/PageHeader";
import PageFooter from "~/components/PageFooter";
import OffcanvasNav from "~/components/OffcanvasNav";

export default {
  name: 'DefaultLayout',
  components: {OffcanvasNav, PageFooter, PageHeader, VueScrollProgressBar},
}
</script>
<style lang="scss">
.progress-bar-container--container {
  top: auto !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
}
</style>
```

I think it has something to do with the build processing, so this is my build properties in the nuxt.config.js:

```js
  build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    html: {
      minify: {
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        preserveLineBreaks: false,
      }
    },
    extend (config, ctx) {

      config.node = {
        fs: 'empty'
      }

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.mjs$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        type: "javascript/auto"
      });
    },
  },
```

I'm at a loss at the moment on how to figure it out. Hoping someone can point me to a solution.

Comment: Have you tried it locally? How do you run it locally? Like `yarn generate && yarn preview`? Do you have a public repo of the project?

Comment: @kissu yes I have. Behaviour is identical. I run yarn 'yarn dev', which executes this command from my package.json: "dev": "nuxt". My site is not static by the way. The repo is not public, but I can share it privately with you.

Comment: Behavior identical -> you should then debug locally, nothing related to a production build. Package you're currently using is a bit dated (no updates for several years), I would recommend using some more supported like a VueUse `useScroll` + `useNProgress` combo or something similar. Having it done manually should be feasible and you'll have less issues overall. Consider moving towards Nuxt3, Nuxt2 is End of Life since 2024. Importing plugins in Nuxt is not done the same way, especially for those not handling SSR by default. "My site is not static" -> Using `ssr: true` + `target: 'server'`?

Comment: Sorry, but with identical I meant that locally in development all is fine, in production it isn't. Just as on the server. Production mode debugging is difficult, or at least I don't know how. 

Both ssr and target have the values you mentioned by default according to the docs. So they should be just that.

Comment: Hence why I'm recommending `yarn generate && yarn preview` locally so that it's faster and a bit easier to debug. Where do you host your app btw? If you haven't yet, give a try to Netlify or Vercel, even tho it sounds strange that the issue is only on production and not reproducible locally. I saw it poorly but you have not tried `progressbar.client.js` btw. Also, the author probably meant that it doesn't support SSR overall so there is no way it works with the defaults out of the box. Since SSR is probably important to you, give a try to a `client` plugin or use `client-only`.

Comment: @kissu wrapping the component in <ClientOnly> did the trick. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.